# Question on finding $\pi_1 (\mathbb R P^n),$ for $n \geq 2.$

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups, projective-space

> Compute $\pi_1(\mathbb R P^n),$ for $n \geq 2.$

> $\textbf {My Attempt} :$ Consider the covering quotient map $p : S^n \longrightarrow \mathbb R P^n.$ Let $\gamma$ be any loop in $\mathbb R P^n$ based at $[e].$ Consider the unique lift $\widetilde {\gamma}$ which begins at $e.$ Then either $\widetilde {\gamma}$ is a loop at $e$ or it is a path in $S^n$ from $e$ to $-e.$ In the former case $\widetilde\gamma \simeq *$ since $S^n$ is simply-connected for $n \geq 2$ and hence $\gamma \simeq *.$ In the later case $\gamma \not\simeq *$ for otherwise by homotopy lifting property $\widetilde {\gamma} \simeq *,$ a contradiction. Hence there are only two homotopy classes of loops based at $[e]$ in $\mathbb R P^n$ and hence $\pi_1(\mathbb R P^n) \cong \mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z,$ for $n \geq 2.$

Can anybody check my attempt above and confirm whether it is fine or not? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: You're almost correct. More precisely, you want to show that there are exactly 2 possible lifts up to homotopy. All you've actually shown is that each lift is either $*$ or not $*$. So you want to state that any two paths from $e$ to $-e$ are homotopy equivant, so each path $\gamma$ is either the image of the unique path $e$ to $e$ or the image of the unique path $e$ to $-e$, and the two are not equal. This lets you conclude there are exactly 2 elements in $\pi_1(\mathbb{R} P^n)$.

Comment: @Mark Saving isn't it again a consequence of homotopy lifting?

Comment: Yes, but all you've stated is "In the latter case, $\gamma \neq *$. This isn't enough to establish that all $\gamma$ which aren't $*$ are the same.